# Matching if all of BCD..n exist after last occurrence of A

Tags: regex

I have a source string that looks like this: `mID00231mID00008mID00231mID00054mID00013mID00008mID00065`

The pattern I am trying to create, using this example, is: For the last occurrence of "mID00231" in the string, **one or more** occurrences of **each of** {mID00054, mID00013, mID00008, mID00065} must follow it (in **any order**).

Examples of matches:

```
mID00231mID00008mID00231mID00054mID00013mID00008mID00065
mID00231mID00013mID00054mID00008mID00065mID00008
```

Example of no match because of missing "mID00065":

```
mID00231mID00054mID00013mID00008
```

Example of no match because the last occurrence of "mID00231" is not followed by a "mID00054" and a "mID00008":

```
mID00231mID00013mID00065mID00054mID00008mID00231mID00013mID00065
```

I am fairly new to regex but usually arrive at something that works. This one has been very difficult. I tried this:

```
(?:mID00231)(?:(?=.*mID00054)(?=.*mID00013)(?=.*mID00008)(?=.*mID00065).*)
```

It works if there is only one occurrence of the first element (mID00231). If the element repeats, the pattern fails. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "followed by", do you mean "immediately followed by"?

Comment: This regex `mID00231((?=(?:(?!mID00231).)*mID00054)(?=(?:(?!mID00231).)*mID00013)(?=(?:(?!mID00231).)*mID00008)(?=(?:(?!mID00231).)*mID00065)(?:(?!mID00231).)*)` looks horrible. Are you sure you need a regex?

Comment: Ok, you may replace the tempered greedy tokens with simpler lookaheads.

Comment: @redneb: If you are asking about my 'no match' example where I use  "followed by" then what I mean is that it is not a match because the two tokens (mID00054 and mID00008) do not exist in the string after the last occurrence of mID00231.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fail the match if there is the same value with a negative lookahead:

```
mID00231((?!.*mID00231)(?=.*mID00054)(?=.*mID00013)(?=.*mID00008)(?=.*mID00065).*)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI6tH1/1).

**Details**:

- `mID00231` - match a literal `mID00231` text
- `(` - start of the capturing group

  - `(?!.*mID00231)` - there cannot be `mID00231` anywhere after 0+ any chars but a newline
  - `(?=.*mID00054)` - there must be  `mID00054` anywhere after 0+ any chars but a newline
  - `(?=.*mID00013)` - there must be  `mID00013` anywhere after 0+ any chars but a newline
  - `(?=.*mID00008)` - there must be  `mID00008` anywhere after 0+ any chars but a newline
  - `(?=.*mID00065)` - there must be  `mID00065` anywhere after 0+ any chars but a newline
- `.*`  - 0+ any chars but a newline
- `)` - end of the capturing group.