# If A exists then match all of BCD..n after last occurrence of A, else any of BCD..n

Tags: java, regex

I asked the question, [Matching if all of BCD..n exist after last occurrence of A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476381/matching-if-all-of-bcd-n-exist-after-last-occurrence-of-a), just yesterday, which resulted in a quick and accurate answer (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI6tH1/1)). I thought I could do this next part on my own but am having difficulty inserting the pattern into look-ahead constructs to simulate an If-Then-Else Conditional, which the Java regex engine does not support. Here is the updated problem statement:

- **IF** "mID00231" exists in the source string

  - **THEN** for the last occurrence of "mID00231" in the string, **one or more** occurrences of **each of** {mID00054, mID00013, mID00008, mID00065} must follow it (in **any order**),
- **ELSE**

  - **one or more** occurrences of **any of** {mID00054, mID00013, mID00008, mID00065} must occur.

Matching source strings will look like these:

```
mID00231mID00008mID00054mID00013mID00065
mID00231mID00008mID00231mID00054mID00013mID00008mID00065
mID00054mID00065mID00008
```

Example of no match because of missing "mID00065":

```
mID00231mID00054mID00013mID00008
```

Example of no match because the last occurrence of "mID00231" is not followed by a "mID00054" and a "mID00008":

```
mID00231mID00013mID00065mID00054mID00008mID00231mID00013mID00065
```

I have tried putting solution provided in the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI6tH1/1) into a "(THEN(?=IF))|(ELSE(?!IF))" look-ahead construct, but so far have been wildly unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use two separate regex tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:mID00231(?!.*mID00231)(?=.*mID00054)(?=.*mID00013)(?=.*mID00008)(?=.*mID00065))|(?:^(?!.*mID00231)((?=.*mID00054)|(?=.*mID00013)|(?=.*mID00008)|(?=.*mID00065)))
```

Breaking it down:

- Two alternatives separated by `|`

  - First alternative in `(?:...)` (the `?:` to create a non-remembered group)

    - `mID00231` finds the literal string followed by...
    - `(?!.*mID00231)` NO occurrence of `mID00231`,
    - `(?=.*mID00054)` any occurrence of `mID00054`,
    - `(?=.*mID00013)` any occurrence of `mID00013`,
    - `(?=.*mID00008)` any occurrence of `mID00008`, **AND**
    - `(?=.*mID00065)` any occurrence of `mID00065`
  - Second alternative in `(?:...)`

    - `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string
    - `(?!.*mID00231)` NO occurrence of `mID00231`, followed by...
    - Four alternatives in `(?:...)`

      - `(?=.*mID00054)` any occurrence of `mID00054`,
      - `(?=.*mID00013)` any occurrence of `mID00013`,
      - `(?=.*mID00008)` any occurrence of `mID00008`, **OR**
      - `(?=.*mID00065)` any occurrence of `mID00065`